# Safely get next SQL Server sequence value from .NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sequence, sql-server-2012

I'm experimenting with SEQUENCE objects in SQL Server, and getting the next value with C# by specifying the sequence name. Ranges are simple, because there is a stored procedure for them, and you can pass the sequence name;

```
    public static T Reserve<T>(string name, int count, SqlConnection sqlConn)
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_sequence_get_range", sqlConn))
        {
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var firstValueParam = new SqlParameter("@range_first_value", SqlDbType.Variant) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sequence_name", name);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@range_size", count);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(firstValueParam);

            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (T)firstValueParam.Value;
        }
    }
```

But what about single values? It seems to me that I can either call the above with a count of '1', or I can construct the SQL dynamically. i.e.

```
var sqlCmdStr = string.Format("SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR {0}", name);
```

Which I know to generally be bad practice (i.e. SQL injection).

What would anyone suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is a combination of both @Gserg's answer and your current solution. Write a stored procedure that takes a `VARCHAR` parameter @Name. Build the sql string in the stored procedure, using `QUOTENAME` as suggested by @GSerg. Use `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` to run the script.

Something like this (freehand):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetNext]
    @Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(200);
    SET @Name = QUOTENAME(@Name, '[');
    SET @sql = 'SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR ' + @Name;

    EXEC (@sql);
END
```

Comment: This looks the most sensible and most flexible to me. I wouldn't want to maintain a list of available sequences in code. I'll test this against the sp_sequence_get_range with a 1 range size to see if there is any difference in performance (not that it's an issue!). Thanks.

Comment: Surround @Sql part in EXEC statement with Parentheses. Because EXEC is for stored procedures where as EXEC() (which is a function) used for dynamic string execution.

It should end with EXEC (@sql);

Answer (score 5):

> Which I know to generally be bad practice (i.e. SQL injection).

Not every dynamic SQL is evil.

Whether you are open to SQL injection depends on where the value (that gets inserted in SQL text) comes from. If it comes from a place under a tight control of your code (e.g. a `switch` statement that chooses from a set of string constants) then SQL injection is not an issue.

Or, you could simply have a separate query for each sequence (assuming you don't have very many of them).

Comment: Not just where the inserted text comes from, but also the type.  If the inserted text is from an int then there should be no risk of injection.

Answer (score 1):

Another version of Paul's solution, which will return formatted alphanumeric Key from SQL Sequence

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_GetNextKey]
@Name NVARCHAR(50),
@FormatText NVARCHAR(50)
AS

--DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(50)='CustomerKeySequence'
--DECLARE @FormatText NVARCHAR(50) = 'CUS0000#'

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(200) = 'SELECT FORMAT((NEXT VALUE FOR ' + QUOTENAME(@Name, '"') + '),'+QUOTENAME(@FormatText, '''')+')';
EXEC (@sql)

/*
RETURNS i.e CUS00184
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to do a similar thing, I do this:

```
string sanitized_name;
using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("select quotename(@unsafe_name, '[');", sqlConn))
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unsafe_name", name);

    sanitized_name = (string)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select next value for {0};", sanitized_name), sqlConn))
{
    ...
}
```

Or create a server-side procedure that does the same.

Comment: Is it really worth that additional SQL call to quote the field? It would be much better to mimic quotename in CLR code.

Comment: @flem Would you bet your annual salary on getting it right the first time?

Comment: That's what tests are for. You're never expected to get it right first time.

Comment: @Flem If I were your employer I would rate you very much so on your ability to "get it right the first time" and would set as a minimum that you did so close to 90% of the time for non prototype code. I would also require you to reexamine your understanding of "what tests are for"

Comment: @CasperLeonNielsen. I agree with what you say about setting targets to "get it right" more often but don't believe it's an expectation. What I expect is that my team "get it right". I don't care if it takes 10 times as long as it's done the best it can be done and in a reasonable amount of time. When I said "that's what tests are for" I was referring to TDD. Unit testing would quickly determine the quality of such a method "quotename". Do you think MS have their SQL Server engine developers "get it right first time" and then not test it?

Comment: @Flem In light of your nuanced response, I think I would like you on my team ; )